# How to refresh random JS variables in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a script in Google Sheets that generates a random Hiragana character and it works fine, but it doesn't refresh the random unless I rewrite the function. Is there a way to refresh random JavaScript elements without having to rewrite the function or putting it back in the sheet?

Here is my code:

```
function RandomVowel() {
  var array = ["あ","い","う","え","お"];
  var RandomValue = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return RandomValue
}
```

Comment: If you are using `RandomVowel()` as the custom function, is this information useful? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+custom+function+refresh

Comment: Hi, I have tried your function in different cells of the sheet and every time I am getting a different value, even if I rewrite in these cells (therefore meaning it works). What do you mean by **it doesn't refresh unless I rewrite the function** ? What is your context, how do you want to refresh the sheet (for example, do you want the value to change every time you open the spreadsheet) ? Sharing a sample sheet might help me understanding your intentions (with no sensitive data). Thanks :D

Comment: What I mean by re-writing is that I have a specific sheet for practicing this and it will only refresh if I delete everything and then put the function back in. What I want to do is to maybe make another function that will refresh all of the JS variables or make it so that it refreshes if I reload the page or for example off-screen the problems. Right now, the only way I can refresh everything is by deleting the cells, then putting the function back in or editing the script. I have set cells that I want to put the function in so it will work on new cells but since I have set cells, it doesn't

Comment: It doesn't change

Comment: Hi ! Have you tried using an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) or [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger ? These type of funcions could make your values to change every time period, whenever you edit your sheet or as you mentioned **every time you open the spreadsheet**? Would this fit in an answer to your question?

Comment: I indeed have done that by setting recalculation to every minute but it doesn't seem to recalculate the JS variables but only the sheet variables like Rand() and Date(). However, I haven't tried the simple triggers so I will look into those. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

In order to be able to execute the [installable time trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) you mentioned every minute you should execute the function in the cell you want to use from your script instead of calling the function in the sheet as a formula.

To achieve what you are aiming for you must first create a time based installable trigger *(in your script IDE go to **Edit -> Current project's triggers** and create a new trigger with your function name, time based and to run it every minute)* and then run the following self explained piece of code:

```js
function RandomVowel() {
  var array = ["あ","い","う","え","お"];
  var RandomValue = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  
  // Get the sheet you want your characters to be shown
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Choose the cell you want to set to these random values every minute
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(RandomValue);
  // For a range of cells
  // sheet.getRange('B1:C3').setValues(RandomValue);
}
```

To achieve this in a range, you must first wrap the part where we set the values into two for loops (one for rows and one for columns) to make sure that in every single iteration the random value will be different (as oppossed to just set the variable to the whole range which would cause all the cells to have the same value).

In the following example we are setting the first 10 rows and 2 columns to these random values (i.e from `A1:B10`):

```js
function RandomVowel() {
  var array = ["あ","い","う","え","お"];
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Sets the first 10 rows of the first 2 column to random values (i.e A1:B10)
  for(j=0;j<2;j++){ // for the columns
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){ // for the rows
      var RandomValue = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
      sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1).setValue(RandomValue);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: So do I just put the sheet name that I want this function to be in and the range and it will refresh every minute? Thank you!

Comment: One issue, overall it works, but over the range it comes with the same value instead of all being different. The answer works with a setup but is there a way to make sure all of them are different?

Comment: Yes, put the sheet name. For doing this with a range instead of with a cell I have updated my answer to cover that as well (you will need to set up the random variable on every iteration to make sure every cell of the range gets a random value).